# ReferenceError in panel due to scope

Tags: button, extjs, handler

I'm trying to call a function from initComponent. However, I'm unable to get the scope of this object, thus running into ReferenceErrors.
The function I'm calling is getFileType and it's missing the scope and I'm unable to get it. (line nos: 204).
Is there a way to change scope inside the handler.

Also, by adding scope:this inside the button, I'm losing scope to pick the form data...

Any help here would be awesome!

```
Ext.define('D.application.component.de.AddConnectionPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.form.FieldSet',

initComponent : function()
    {
            var databaseConnDetails = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
                            bodyPadding: 15,
                        //  width:'auto',
                            region:'center',
                            layout:{
                                align: 'center',
                            },
                            defaults: {
                                anchor: '100%',
                            },
                            title: 'Database Details',
                            items: [{
                                    defaults: {

                                    },
                                    items: [{
                                            readOnly: false,
                                            hidden: false,
                                            xtype: 'dsqcombobox',
                                            name: 'DB_TYPE',
                                            emptyText: 'DB Type',
                                            flex: 1,
                                            fieldID: 'Field-1',
                                    }],
                                    layout: 'hbox',
                                    xtype: 'dsqfieldcontainer',
                                    layoutID: 'Contain_1',
                            },
                            {
                                    defaults: {

                                    },
                                    items: [{
                                            readOnly: false,
                                            hidden: false,
                                            xtype: 'dsqtextfield',
                                            name: 'DB_URL',
                                            emptyText: 'DB Url',
                                            flex: 1,
                                            fieldID: 'Field-2',
                                    },
                                    {
                                            readOnly: false,
                                            hidden: false,
                                            xtype: 'dsqtextfield',
                                            name: 'DB_PORT',
                                            emptyText: 'DB Port',
                                            flex: 1,
                                            fieldID: 'Field-3',
                                    }],
                                    layout: 'hbox',
                                    xtype: 'dsqfieldcontainer',
                                    layoutID: 'Contain_2',
                            },
                            {
                                    defaults: {

                                    },
                                    items: [{
                                            readOnly: false,
                                            hidden: false,
                                            xtype: 'dsqtextfield',
                                            name: 'DB_SCHEMA',
                                            emptyText: 'Schema Name',
                                            flex: 1,
                                            fieldID: 'Field-4',
                                    },
                                    {
                                            readOnly: false,
                                            hidden: false,
                                            xtype: 'dsqtextfield',
                                            name: 'DB_LABEL',
                                            emptyText: 'Schema Label',
                                            flex: 1,
                                            fieldID: 'Field-6',
                                    }],
                                    layout: 'hbox',
                                    xtype: 'dsqfieldcontainer',
                                    layoutID: 'Contain_4',
                            },
                            {
                                    defaults: {

                                    },
                                    items: [{
                                            readOnly: false,
                                            hidden: false,
                                            xtype: 'dsqtextarea',
                                            name: 'DB_DESCRIPTION',
                                            emptyText: 'Connection Description',
                                            flex: 1,
                                            fieldID: 'Field-6',
                                    }],
                                    layout: 'hbox',
                                    xtype: 'dsqfieldcontainer',
                                    layoutID: 'Contain_6',
                            },
                            {
                                    defaults: {

                                    },
                                    items: [{
                                            readOnly: false,
                                            hidden: false,
                                            xtype: 'dsqtextfield',
                                            name: 'DB_USERNAME',
                                            emptyText: 'DB Username',
                                            flex: 1,
                                            fieldID: 'Field-5',
                                    },
                                    {
                                            readOnly: false,
                                            hidden: false,
                                            xtype: 'dsqtextfield',
                                            name: 'DB_PASSWORD',
                                            inputType: 'password',
                                            emptyText: 'DB Password',
                                            flex: 1,
                                            fieldID: 'Field-6',
                                    }],
                                    layout: 'hbox',
                                    xtype: 'dsqfieldcontainer',
                                    layoutID: 'Contain_7',
                            },
                            {
                                    defaults: {

                                    },
                                    items: [{
                                            readOnly: true,
                                            hidden: true,
                                            xtype: 'dsqtextfield',
                                            name: 'ID',
                                            emptyText: 'Connection ID',
                                            flex: 1,
                                            fieldID: 'Field-6',
                                    }],
                                    layout: 'hbox',
                                    xtype: 'dsqfieldcontainer',
                                    layoutID: 'Contain_8',
                            },
                            {
                                    defaults: {

                                    },
                                    items: [{
                                        readOnly: false,
                                        hidden: false,
                                        width:70,
                                        xtype: 'dsqbutton',
                                        name: 'save',
                                        fieldLabel: 'Save',
                                        fieldID:'Field-8',
                                    }],
                                    layout: {
                                        type: 'hbox',
                                        align: 'middle',
                                        pack: 'center'
                                    },
                                    xtype: 'dsqfieldcontainer',
                                    layoutID: 'Contain_9',
                            }],
                            xtype: 'dsqfieldset',
                            layoutID: 'Connection Details'
            }); 

            var fileConnDetails = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                            bodyPadding:15,
                            defaults: {
                                anchor:'100%',
                            },
                            width:500,
                            title: 'File Details',
                            bodyPadding: 10,
                            frame: true,
                            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                            items: [{
                                xtype: 'filefield',
                                name: 'InputFile',
                                id:'filefield',
                                emptyText: 'File',
                                msgTarget: 'side',
                                allowBlank: false,
                                anchor: '100%',
                                buttonText: 'Browse...'
                            }],

                            buttons: [{
                                text: 'Upload',
                                layout:{
                                    pack:'center',
                                    align:'middle',
                                },
                                handler: function() {
                                    var form = this.up('form').getForm(); // Get form details 
                                    if(form.isValid()){
                                        var fileName = form.findField('filefield').getSubmitValue();                                    
                                        // Check to see if file type is supported
                                        var retVal = getFileType(fileName);
                                        if (retVal != DSQ_SUCCESS){
                                            Ext.Msg.alert('Unsupported File Type');
                                            return;
                                        }

                                        // Parse file and read data
                                        retVal = parseInputFile(fileName, fileArray);
                                        if (retVal != DSQ_SUCCESS) {
                                            Ext.Msg.alert('Error! unable to read file');
                                            return;
                                        }

                                        form.submit({
                                            success: function(fp, action) {
                                                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your file "' + action.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');
                                            },
                                            failure: function(fp, action) {
                                                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', 'File "' + action.result.file + '"  upload failed');
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }]                              
            });

            var connectionInfo = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
                    autoEl:'div',
                    width:700,
                    bodyPadding: 5,  // Don't want content to crunch against the borders
                    layout:'card',
                    items:[{
                        id:'file_card',
                        items:[fileConnDetails],
                    },{
                        id:'db_card',
                        items:[databaseConnDetails],
                    }],
            });

            var DataSourceOptionsContainer = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container',{
                    region:'center',
                    layout:{
                        type:'vbox',
                        align: 'center',
                    },
                    items : [{
                        xtype:'radiogroup',
                        vertical:false,
                        columns:2,
                        items: [{
                                boxLabel: 'Flat-File',
                                name:'datasource',
                                inputValue:'flatfile',
                                width:80,
                                checked:true,
                            },{
                                boxLabel: 'Database',
                                name:'datasource',
                                inputValue:'database',
                                width:80
                        }],
                        listeners: {
                            change: function(radiogroup, newVal, oldVal) {
                                var listenerObj = newVal.datasource;
                                switch(listenerObj) {
                                    case 'database':
                                        connectionInfo.getLayout().setActiveItem('db_card');
                                        break;
                                    case 'flatfile':
                                        connectionInfo.getLayout().setActiveItem('file_card');
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        console.log("No such Object in connection group");
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }],
            });

            var config = {
                    items: [DataSourceOptionsContainer, connectionInfo]
            };

            Ext.apply(this,config);
            this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    getFileType: function(fileName) 
    {
        var fileTypesAllowed = [".csv", ".xls", ".xlsb"];
        alert("File Type verification");
        if(!Ext.Array.contains(fileTypesAllowed, fileName)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 1;
    },      
    parseInputFile: function(fileName, fileArray)
    {
        return 1;
    },
    onRender : function()
    {
            this.callParent(arguments);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the reference to the form panel object in `this` instead of using a local variable:

```
this.fileConnDetails = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
```

(you'll also have to replace further references to that variable in initComponent with `this.fileConnDetails`)

Then, as you suggested, add `scope: this` to your button. You'll then have both the form panel and your functions in the same scope:

```
buttons: [{
    text: 'Upload',
    layout:{
        pack:'center',
        align:'middle',
    },
    handler: function() {
        var form = this.fileConnDetails.getForm(); // Get form details 
        if(form.isValid()){
            var fileName = form.findField('filefield').getSubmitValue();                                    
            // Check to see if file type is supported
            var retVal = this.getFileType(fileName);
            if (retVal != DSQ_SUCCESS){
                Ext.Msg.alert('Unsupported File Type');
                return;
            }

            // Parse file and read data
            retVal = this.parseInputFile(fileName, fileArray);
            if (retVal != DSQ_SUCCESS) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error! unable to read file');
                return;
            }

            form.submit({
                success: function(fp, action) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your file "' + action.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');
                },
                failure: function(fp, action) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', 'File "' + action.result.file + '"  upload failed');
                }
            });
        }
    },
    scope: this
}]
```

Comment: Getting the following error.                                     TypeError: this.fileConnDetails is undefined
var form = this.fileConnDetails.getForm(); // Get form details

Answer (score 0):

`getFileType` is part of your class. You need to add:

```
scope: this,
handler: function() {
    // ....
    this.getFileType();
}
```

Comment: You already have a reference to the form, `databaseConnDetails`.

Comment: It worked with Matt's suggestion. Looks like the problem was getFileType is part of the mainPanel. this.getFileType, could still not find scope. After including it withe the fileConnDetails, they were all in the same scope.